# Article Read More button in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I'm confused. Can somebody please explain to me how the "read more" button works for articles in joomla? I'm trying to make it work for a template made from scratch but the article doesn't show more when I click on the read more button.

Do I need to set another module to put the entire article on? Or do I need to make a new page for viewing the article on? How would I make sure my link would go to the new page? Or is it possible for me to switch the contents of a certain module once I click on read more?

Comment: This isnt an answer, just a work-around.  If you're making a template from scratch I've found that "not using joomla" is the best way to use joomla.  The documentation is atrocious and their methods are convoluted so if you're venturing into new territory then it can be very painful to find comprehensive information to do what you want.  I usually just break down to pure php when working with joomla. I ran into the same problem you had a while back, finally gave up, and used this library: http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/  it's more flexible too.
Have you considered trying Wordpress?

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't use Wordpress as I'm supposed to study Joomla using the current template. Anyway, I've done a work around by checking if the url contains a certain string. From there, I call another module to display the content. To bad I can't get the publish date, author, categories, etc to display

Comment: If the settings are selected to show the date, author, etc and it is still not showing up, if i remember correctly, you need to add an xhtml style to the position like this: <jdoc:include type="modules" name="name of module position" **style="xhtml"** />...actually now that i think about it, that might solve the original problem too.  i didn't find that answer until after i gave up on the "read more" problem

Comment: Thanks. I added style="xhtml" on my jdoc tag. The article title showed up but the other info like author and publish date, it still didn't appear.

Comment: When you click on the readmore like, assuming that the user has access to the article, you get a view of the full article sometimes called the single article view.  This sends you to a separate "page/"
How are you trying to get the article information to display? These are controlled by the global configuration/article/menu item cascade.  xhtml is a style used for modules not components.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I'm not seeing that option you're pointing me to. I'm using Joomla 3.0